# Whether a matrix normed linear space is Banach space or not?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $\mathbf{S}^{n}$ denote the set of $n$-order Hermitian matrices(also a real linear space). Note that it is an inner space  with the inner product defined by
$$
\langle A,B \rangle \overset{def}{=} {\rm tr} (A^{H} B), 
$$
then the norm in $\mathbf{S}^{n}$ is given by
$$
\|A\| \overset{def}{=} \sqrt{\langle A, A \rangle} \quad , \text{for} \ A \in \mathbf{S}^{n}.
$$
Is it true that the normed linear space $\mathbf{S}^{n}$ is a Banach space? If so, then how can we prove it?

Comment: Is it finite-dimensional?

Comment: The set of positive semidefinite matrices do not form a linear space. They do, however, form a cone.

Comment: @BenGrossmann  Thanks for your reminding that it is actually a closed convex cone, I will reconsider my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That the set of (not necessarily positive) self-adjoint operator $S^n$ is a real vector subspace is easy:
\begin{align*}
(S + T )^*& = S^* + T^* = S + T,\\
(\alpha T )^*& = \alpha T^* = \alpha T, \forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R}.\end{align*}

So, probably the question is about the closure of the set:
If $T_n\to T$ with $T^*_n = T_n$, then in the limit, $T^* = T$ by continuity of the adjoint.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, as $\mathbf{S}^{n}$ defined before is an finite dimensional normed linear space, the convergency of sequences by norm in it is equivalent to that by coordinates. Therefore, it is linearly isomorphic and homeomorphic to some definite dimensional real space $\mathbf{R}^{X}$ which is a Banach space. So $\mathbf{S}^{n}$ is of course a Banach space.